# The following code for finding the factorial of a number goes into an infinite loop on Xcode.There is no output shown after taking the number as input

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n,fact = 1;
    printf("Enter a number\n");
    scanf("%d\n",&n);
    while(n > 0)
    {
        fact = fact * n;
        n--;
    }
    printf("Factorial is: %d",fact);
    return 0;
}
```

Please help me find the error with this. I have tried using long and unsigned long int but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Remove the new line character '\n' in the call of scanf scanf("%d",&n);

Comment: What happened when you tried using a debugger to verify that `n` has the value you expect it to? You would notice that it hadn't entered the loop at all, which would point you to the solution offered, or at least to a more refined question.

Answer (score 1):

```
scanf("%d\n",&n);
//       ^^
```

This will read an integer, and then as much whitespace as it can. It does this by reading characters until it finds the first *non-whitespace* character then pushes that back on to the input stream for the next read. From the ISO C11 standard `7.21.6.2 The fscanf function /5`:

> A directive composed of white-space character(s) is executed by reading input up to the first non-white-space character (which remains unread), or until no more characters can be read. The directive never fails.

So, after you enter the integer, your code is still waiting around for the first non-whitespace character. If you actually enter a character (say, `x`) followed by <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, you'll see it continue.

Solution is therefore just to get rid of the `\n` at the end of the format string.

---

Two other suggestions, not related to your problem but useful to know:

- use one of the canonical `main` formats, the one you need for this code is `int main(void)`.
- put a `\n` at the end of your `printf` format string so that it formats the output better.